# Relay contact arcing

Tags: motor, controller

I use a relay with an 80 amp contact rating to start and run a 1 1/2 hp AC pump motor. The points arc badly and soon become unusable.

Is there a way I can add capacitors to the points in this AC circuit to reduce the arcing? Or should I use a contactor, which I’m totally unfamiliar with?

Comment: What voltage is this operating at?  Why capacitors?  Did you know that a contactor (at least for this size motor) is not that much different from a relay?  Do you have overload protection for the motor somewhere?

Comment: It would be helpful to know (provide a datasheet) which relay you are using and also how you are driving its coil.  Also, what is the motor operating voltage?

Comment: This is a simple 110 V AC system controlling the pump in my irrigation system. The sprinkler control system provides 110 V signal to the relay coil to start and run the pump. Another gentleman suggested the use of a solid state relay in the system, which I would really like to do. I am in the process of looking for a suitable solid state relay.

Comment: you could put an SSR in parallel with your relay. get one with a zero-cross detector to avoid any arcs. you could trigger the SSR first by adding capacitance to the relay driver input to slightly delay (1/120th sec) it's turning on. That gives you a lot less heat on the SSR from the voltage drop of the triac and prevents arcing on the low-resistance relay contacts since there's already a better path than air (the on-state triac).

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I have ordered an  SSR.

Comment: I have ordered a 40 amp SSR with a heat sink. I was planning to simply replace the mechanical relay with this SSR. Will this work?